# How to change a row colour based on cell entry in SP

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I've looked at various sources, tried various solutions but nothing seems to work for me. I'm using SP, I don't know which version but it's a later one - it has the option to click back to 'Classic Experience'.

I have a list, and I want to make the **STATUS** field with **Assigned**, **Ongoing**,  and **Complete** change the full row color depending on which option is selected.

I've attached a screenshot of the only field I have which mentions Column formatting. This is all I can find that seems to have anything to do with JSON. I've put various formulas in there but at best, the option selected in the status field vanishes from view and it's just blank, at worst it gives me an error about illegal character entry.

Here are various examples I've tried:

```
{
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if([$Status] == 'Complete', 'sp-field-severity--good', if([$Status] == 'Ongoing', 'sp-field-severity--low' ,if([$Status] == 'Assigned', 'sp-field-severity--low' ,''))))"
}

{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
        "color": "=if([$Status] != 'Complete' , 'red' , '')"
    },
    "txtContent": "@currentField"
}



{
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if([$Status] == 'Assigned', 'sp-field-severity--good', if([$Status] == 'Ongoing', 'sp-field-severity--low' ,if([$Status] == 'Complete','sp-field-severity--warning', ''))))"
}

{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if(@currentField == 'Assigned', '#008000', if([$Date] < @now , '#ff0000',if([$Date] > @now, '#FFFF00', '#00FF00')))"
  }
}




{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(@currentField == 'Assigned', 'sp-field-severity--good', if(@currentField == 'Ongoing', 'sp-field-severity--low', if(@currentField == 'Complete', 'sp-field-severity--warning')))) + ' ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary'"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(@currentField == 'Assigned', 'CheckMark', if(@currentField == 'Ongoing', 'Forward', if(@currentField == 'Complete', 'Error'))))"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
  ]
```

Edit: Sorry, don't know why I can't get the image to show. It's here:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirements, you have to use the JSON **View formatting** in SharePoint.

Use below JSON:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
    "additionalRowClass": "=if([$Status] == 'Complete', 'sp-field-severity--good', if([$Status] == 'Ongoing', 'sp-field-severity--low', if([$Status] == 'Assigned', 'sp-field-severity--warning', '')))"
}
```

Where `Status` is **internal name** of your choice column. Check below article to find out the internal name of SharePoint column:

[Find the internal name of SharePoint column](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Make sure you are using correct internal name & adding the JSON at right place like below:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)

---

**Update from comments**:

View formatting is currently supported only in SharePoint Online and not in SharePoint 2019.

Comment: Hi, thanks Ganesh. I've seen your answers elsewhere and tried to get them to work but to no avail unfortunately.

When I click 'All Items' in the list, the drop-down only shows me:

Items that need attention
All Items
Save View As
Edit Current View

How would I activate or find this View Formatting?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using custom list or any other list template? Also, do you see column formatting option for any column? If yes, you can open the json formatting pane using column formatting & then select "Format View" & "List" in Choose layout as shown in above image.

Comment: Hi Ganesh. I'm using a custom list. I've also identified it's SP19 that we're using.

I can't find a column formatting option. All I see is the conditional formatting box.

Comment: Unfortunately, View formatting is currently supported only in SharePoint Online. So, you cannot use this in SP 2019.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ganesh, sorry to have wasted your time.